# VMware fusion - can you increase the video ram size past 128MB?

Tags: windows-8, osx-mavericks, vmware-fusion

I'm trying out VMWare Fusion 6 on my Mac (Mavericks) and I'm running Windows 8 x64 inside Fusion.  The problem is that I cannot find a way to increase the video ram past 128MB.  I tried editing the the vmx file to increase the video memory, but Win8 System Info tells me the video memory is still at 128MB.  Is there a hard limit for the maximum amount of video memory that can be allocated to a Virtual Machine in VMWare?

Using parallels desktop 9, I can get my Win8 VM to use 1GB of video ram, so I can't see why VMware wouldn't allow me to do that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1001876:

> This article provides information about reducing the size of the video
>   memory (vRAM) allocated by Fusion.
>
> Note: Fusion assigns 128 MB by default and does not support assigning
>   more.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have more than 128MB dedicated for video memory? With win8 you may be using RAM in place of video memory

Go to system profile and see what you are running for dedicated video memory. In a lot of older computers they have 256mb< for video memory.

If you haven't already edit the .vmx and add

```
svga.vramSize = 1073741824
```

Comment: Hi there, I do have up to 1GB available (NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB).

Comment: Yeah, I had already tried setting the vramSize to 256/512/1GB but it never went past 128MB.